# Nagios / Check_MK web interface host visibility

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I am using Nagios with Check_MK addon at a small ISP company I work for. I am a sole Nagios admin, but we have a few users who use the Nagios / Check_MK system (with Check_MK as the web frontend).

As most devices we use are MikroTik routers with proprietary OS within which I cannot install the check_mk agent (have to use SNMP), I am using Check_MK with `generate_hostconf = False` - I have to manually define WiFi interface checks (like signal strength check) anyways, so all host configuration is done in Nagios files.

All users who use the system are listed in `cgi.cfg` with `authorized_for_all_services=user1,user2` and `authorized_for_all_hosts=user1,user2` etc.

As I was not satisfied with the current configuration (there is not enough serverity-based differentiation among different hosts and service types - i.e. we want not only backbone / not-monitored host differentiation, but something more fine-grained like backbone / distribution layer 1 / distribution layer 2 / not-monitored client-side), I started to change the configuration to somewhat hackish setup with multiple contacts per real user, with different timeperiods assigned, so that e.g. 'distribution-layer 2' hosts don't wake people at 3 a.m. Perhaps this is not the proper way to do the thing.

Anyways, here is the problem - I created new contacts and contact groups and some rules for inventory - for services it works fine, it seems, but **apparently hosts are not visible in Check_MK web interface (but they are visible in our Nagios website)**. Most likely it is so due to the fact I am logged in as the 'old' user, who is not a part of the new contact group, but still who is supposed to see all hosts (as defined in `cgi.cfg`). **Can I do something to make hosts visible in Check_MK GUI with that setup and not only in Nagios web interface?**

I had to use `check_mk --flush hostname` and re-inventory with `check_mk -II hostname` even after changing the settings back to the previous state to make the hosts appear again.

I haven't tried to add new contacts to `.htaccess`, as I don't really want to create multiple contacts with login permissions. **Does Check_mk simply ignore the `authorized_for_all_hosts / services` directive defined in `cgi.cfg` in this case?**

I can see that Check_MK itself is able to communicate with those hosts not show in GUI - I can do `check_mk -II hostname` or `check_mk -N hostname`. Appropriate entries are present in `etc/check_mk.d/check_mk_objects.cfg` and `nagios/var/retention.dat`; hostnames are listed with `check_mk --list-tag TAG` etc. so most likely it is a problem with GUI user permissions only.

I know I could use `notification_period` directives for hosts and custom SNMP services within Nagios configuration files and `extra_service_conf['notification_period']` in `main.mk`, but I am actually using that for some exceptional cases and wasn't sure about the precedence rules.

Anyways, it is Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS x86_64, Nagios Core 3.4.1, Check_MK 1.2.0p3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is enough to use `default_user_role = "admin"` in `multisite.mk`. Perhaps not the safest thing, but it gets the job done in this setup.